# how to prevent a ball from bouncing only vertically

Tags: unity

I am trying to make a ball bounce off (and also sideways) when it gets into contact with another object. I am having an issue shown in the image below, where the ball rests on the triangle instead of falling off sideways. I tried playing round values for the bounciness and friction, but that didn't solve my issue. How can I solve this issue. I've added the inspector settings on the ball.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try spawning the ball with a very small decay of x,z as random(-1, 1)

Comment: @CedricMartens I don't really understand how to spawn the ball as you recommended. I would appreciate some further explanation.

Comment: Surely that is the correct physics behavior. If a ball falls **exactly** on a pin it will balence. I think cedric is suggesting making it not quite exactly land on the pin but off to one side slightly

Comment: Yes, @RichardTingle points out exactly what I meant. If a ball falls exactly on the point, being balanced is the correct behavior. So if you want it to fall randomly, you need to move it slightly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a little randomness into your physics like so:

```
// Populate this with how much you want to nudge the ball.
public float jitterAmount = 1f;

// Populate this with a layer ID that identifies your triangles to bounce off of.
public int pinLayer;

// Populate this in the Inspector or in Start to point at the ball's Rigidbody2D
Rigidbody2D myBody;

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if(collision.otherGameObject.layer != pinLayer)
        return; // Only jitter sideways off the pins, not other balls / the floor.

    if(Mathf.Abs(myBody.velocity.x) >= 1f)
        return; // Object already has substantial sideways motion.

    Vector2 normal = collision.contacts[0].normal;

    if(Mathf.Abs(normal.x) > 0.01f)
        return; // We've fallen onto a slope that doesn't need help.

    // Add a little nudge left or right:
    myBody.velocity += jitterAmount * (Random.value > 0.5f ? Vector2.right : Vector2.left);
}
```

You can also do this in OnCollisionExit to catch bounces that exactly cancel the incoming horizontal velocity. Here I used OnCollisionEnter to catch non-bouncing collisions too, where the ball falls and rests on the pin.

Comment: It solves my issue when `jitterAmount > 1f` at times, but at times it doesn't. From my observation, it doesn't work when the ball's xPosition and the triangles are extremely close (in some cases correct to several digits) to each other. I am thinking of a way to factor that into your solution. Any ideas?

Comment: It could be that we're falling ever so slightly to one side of the triangle, and half the time we apply a sideways velocity straight into it which is then opposed & neutralised by the collision. Can you check what kinds of collision normals you're getting in these situations? If they have a lean to them, we can amplify that. Else we might need to make our decision based on the point of contact.

Comment: Sorry, I know might be out of the scope of this question, but I've not found anything quite straightforward from a Google search and forum searches. How do I find collision normals?

Comment: `collision.contacts[0].normal`

Comment: Thanks. Mainly, I get `(-0.7, 0.7)` and `(0.7, 0.7)` when it's working, but every time it doesn't work I get `(0.0, 1.0)` for the contact normal.

Comment: How can the contact normals help me solve this issue?

Comment: @SuperHyperMegaSomething have you been able to solve this? I tried working on something similar a while ago.

Comment: @Bane No, I'm still trying to get it done

Comment: Making the tests for sideways motion a bit less exacting as shown above seems to tackle the worst cases in my tests. I added a check on normal, so we don't apply the jitter when falling on a significant slope, even with the more permissive velocity criteria.

Comment: You may also be able to add a small amount of randomness to the underlying geometry to avoid this.  You'd only need to change the surface normals by a very small amount so that x values didn't sum to exactly  0, but I have no idea how easy this is to do in Unity, or how to go about it.  The benefit of this approach is it shouldn't add any overhead to your collision response.

Comment: That sounds like an answer worth posting on its own. The challenge is that our colliders are often primitives (circles, boxes, etc.) rather than meshes where we might be used to individually tweaking normals.

Comment: @DMGregory Sorry for not marking it as correct earlier. Thanks a lot. That solves it, but I'm trying to sort out a peculiar case that happens once a while as seen in this image link http://imgur.com/a/xqmRd. The rectangular game objects border the ball for a while till the ball has stops moving. After any of the rectangular objects fall (without getting into contact with the ball) the ball doesn't move again. I guess that since the code is in `OnCollisionEnter2D` this isn't catered for.

Comment: That's correct. You can ask a new question to dig deeper into this case if you want. You could also consider adding a ball manager that checks all the balls to see if they're at rest periodically and tries to give them a nudge, rather than doing it on collision only.